How to get the correct answer in bomblab
When I do the bomblab phase_4:
`Dump of assembler code for function phase_4:
   0x000000000040108b <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000000000040108f <+4>:     mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x0000000000401098 <+13>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x000000000040109d <+18>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x000000000040109f <+20>:    lea    0x4(%rsp),%rcx
   0x00000000004010a4 <+25>:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x00000000004010a7 <+28>:    mov    $0x40298d,%esi
   0x00000000004010ac <+33>:    call   0x400c40 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x00000000004010b1 <+38>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x00000000004010b4 <+41>:    jne    0x4010bc <phase_4+49>
   0x00000000004010b6 <+43>:    cmpl   $0xe,(%rsp)
   0x00000000004010ba <+47>:    jbe    0x4010c1 <phase_4+54>
   0x00000000004010bc <+49>:    call   0x4016a4 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010c1 <+54>:    mov    $0xe,%edx
   0x00000000004010c6 <+59>:    mov    $0x0,%esi
   0x00000000004010cb <+64>:    mov    (%rsp),%edi
   0x00000000004010ce <+67>:    call   0x401058 <func4>
   0x00000000004010d3 <+72>:    cmp    $0x1f,%eax
   0x00000000004010d6 <+75>:    jne    0x4010df <phase_4+84>
   0x00000000004010d8 <+77>:    cmpl   $0x1f,0x4(%rsp)
   0x00000000004010dd <+82>:    je     0x4010e4 <phase_4+89>
   0x00000000004010df <+84>:    call   0x4016a4 <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004010e4 <+89>:    mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
   0x00000000004010e9 <+94>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00000000004010f2 <+103>:   je     0x4010f9 <phase_4+110>
   0x00000000004010f4 <+105>:   call   0x400b90 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
   0x00000000004010f9 <+110>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x00000000004010fd <+114>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disas func4
Dump of assembler code for function func4:
   0x0000000000401058 <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000401059 <+1>:     mov    %edx,%eax
   0x000000000040105b <+3>:     sub    %esi,%eax
   0x000000000040105d <+5>:     mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x000000000040105f <+7>:     shr    $0x1f,%ebx
   0x0000000000401062 <+10>:    add    %ebx,%eax
   0x0000000000401064 <+12>:    sar    %eax
   0x0000000000401066 <+14>:    lea    (%rax,%rsi,1),%ebx
   0x0000000000401069 <+17>:    cmp    %edi,%ebx
   0x000000000040106b <+19>:    jle    0x401079 <func4+33>
   0x000000000040106d <+21>:    lea    -0x1(%rbx),%edx
   0x0000000000401070 <+24>:    call   0x401058 <func4>
   0x0000000000401075 <+29>:    add    %ebx,%eax
   0x0000000000401077 <+31>:    jmp    0x401089 <func4+49>
   0x0000000000401079 <+33>:    mov    %ebx,%eax
   0x000000000040107b <+35>:    cmp    %edi,%ebx
   0x000000000040107d <+37>:    jge    0x401089 <func4+49>
   0x000000000040107f <+39>:    lea    0x1(%rbx),%esi
   0x0000000000401082 <+42>:    call   0x401058 <func4>
   0x0000000000401087 <+47>:    add    %ebx,%eax
   0x0000000000401089 <+49>:    pop    %rbx
   0x000000000040108a <+50>:    ret
End of assembler dump.`

I translate my func4 as
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int func4(int x,int y,int z)  //t->%rax,k->%ebx,x->edi,y->esi,z->edx
{
    int t=z-y;
    int k=t>>31;
//  if(t>=0) k=0;
//  else k=1;
    t=(t+k)>>1;
    k=t+y;
    if(k>x)
    {
        z=k-1;
        func4(x,y,z);
        t+=k;
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        t=k;
        if(k<x)
        {
            y=k+1;
            func4(x,y,z);
            t+=k;
            return t;
        }
        else
        {
            return t;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    for(int a=15;;a--)
    {
        if(func4(a,0,14)==31)cout<<a;
        
    }
}


I think the initial value of %rsi is 0 and initial value of %rdx is 14.
This is obviously a recursive program, and I translate it into c code. I have traversed all the values of a, but none of them are valid outputs. I don't know where my mistake lies, or if this bomb itself is unsolvable(I am a beginner, please forgive me if there are any problems)

Hello, seniors, how can I make more people see my problem and solve it
